# Enter directory with given string in bash

Tags: bash

I have a number of directories I want to enter and all start with the same string "example". Beyond, in the same location, there are also other directories that I do NOT want to enter.
I was used to loop in this way:

```
for dir1 in */
```

before other directories with other names were present in the same location, but now I cannot anymore. I tried to vary the command using:

```
for dir1 in "example"*/
```

or
    for dir1 in example*/
        cd "dir1"

but it does not enter the directory.
It says: `line 8: cd: example*//: file or directory does not exist`.
How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try `for dir1 in example*/` without the quotes?

Comment: yep, it does not work as well.

Comment: Specifically what are you trying to match? If I have a folder with directories that start with "c", I can do `for x in c*/; do echo $x; done` and it gives me the directory names that begin with "c". Could you please clarify what your statement, "does not work" means?

Comment: I edited my original text to clarify the question. Thanks.

Comment: "line 8"? Could you show the whole part of the script starting at the `for` through to and including the `cd` command that failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell expands the wildcard

```
for dir1 in */
```

into a list of wildcard matches;

```
for dir1 in ack/ bar/ foo/ nst/ pth/ quux/
```

If you want to exclude `foo` and `bar` from this list, the simplest to explain is to enable extended globbing, assuming you have Bash;

```
shopt -s extglob
for dir1 in !(foo|bar)*/
```

but any trick to exclude the files you don't want from matching the wildcard is okay.  In this particular case, you could do

```
for dir1 in [!bf]*/
```

but in the pessimal case, you just have to break down and list the directories you do want to match.  Or maybe just bypass the undesired ones separately:

```
for dir1 in */; do
    case $dir1 in bar|foo) continue ;; esac
    : ... your code here
done
```

If indeed you want to loop over all the directories whose names start with `example` and no others, then the way to do that is certainly

```
for dir1 in example*/
```

The error message you got seemed to indicate that there are no directories with this name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `bash` one liner,

```
for dir in example*; do if [ -d $dir ];then cd $dir; pwd; echo $dir; fi; done
```

Bash script,

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in example*
do 
   if [ -d $dir ];then 
        cd $dir; 
        pwd; 
        echo $dir; 
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash file name globbing is a slick thing. It may be more convenient to use find instead. Like this:

```
    for dir in `find /cygdrive/c/workspaces/ -name '*log*' -a -type d`; do echo $dir; done
```

'-type d' is for directories only.